# Oracle SQL: Extracting data from multiple tables

Tags: sql, oracle, algorithm, oracle19c

I have 3 tables, say TabA, TabB and TabC. Below are some useful columns in these tables:

```
TabA(ID VARCHAR2 Primary Key, ..)

TabB(ID VARCHAR2, Value CHAR(1), LastUpdated Date)

TabC(ID VARCHAR2 Primary Key, Value CHAR(1), LastUpdated Date)
```

Here `Value` is a flag 'Y' or 'N'. I want to obtain all the `ID`s and their `Value` using these 3 tables. First of all I want to look into all the distinct `ID`s present in all the tables. Since the `Value` is not in TabA, I will look for the `Value` in TabB and TabC only. If for a particular `ID`, the `Value` is not there in any of the table, I will assume it 'N'. Suppose for a particular `ID` the value is in both TabB and TabC, I would like to take the `Value` where `LastUpdated` is greater.

I have tried using loops but this is not very efficient solution. I only need the `Key` and `Value` in the resultant cursors and want to keep a single query for this.

Can someone please help to identify a better solution than using loops.

Edit -

Here is a sample :

Suppose TabA is -

| ID |
| --- |
| 100 |
| 101 |
| 102 |

TabB is -

| ID | Value | LastUpdated |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 99 | Y | 21-May-22 |
| 100 | N | 22-May-22 |
| 103 | N | 23-May-22 |

TabC is -

| ID | Value | LastUpdated |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 102 | Y | 20-May-22 |
| 103 | Y | 24-May-22 |
| 104 | N | 21-May-22 |

The result should be -

| ID | Value | Why? |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 99 | Y | from TabB |
| 100 | N | from TabB |
| 101 | N | In TabA only so defaulting N |
| 102 | Y | from TabC |
| 103 | Y | In TabB and TabC but LastUpdated is greater in TabC so taking TabC value |
| 104 | N | from TabC |

Edit -

Expected result if an ID has same LastUpdated in TabB and TabC but different Values - This can be ignored as it will be a rare case. We can assume that this will never happen.

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected outcome as tables.

Comment: @Jonas Metzler Added a sample data. Please let me know if any other info also required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
SELECT id, value FROM
(SELECT id, value, ROW_NUMBER()
OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY lastupdated DESC) AS rownr
FROM
(SELECT id, 'N' AS value, sysdate AS lastupdated FROM taba
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM tabb) 
AND id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM tabc)
UNION
SELECT id, value, MAX(lastupdated) AS lastupdated
FROM tabb
GROUP BY id, value
UNION
SELECT id, value, MAX(lastupdated) AS lastupdated
FROM tabc
GROUP BY id, value
ORDER BY id, lastupdated DESC)) WHERE rownr = 1;
```

At least in my fiddle example, this works correctly: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=360199e109e9fea23f03dc00174b1ece)

Comment: In the last query for TabC, is there any significance of group by? I mean ID is already unique for TabC, so there will be only one lastupdated for this. Overall, what you have done is, created the union of all the tables with some default values for TabA and taken the max lastupdated for all IDs. For TabA, you handled it by considering only IDs that are not in TabB / TabC. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I recommend to execute the sub queries separately to see the outcome of each of them and the reason why grouping is required. This will help much more than trying to explain this in a comment here. You can use my fiddle or your DB to just play around, because (as you surely know) a query will never change data, so there is no risk to "destroy" anything.

Comment: @TalkChat Admin, Besides, while the group by should not affect result, it may affect performance. Processing 2x number of rows in operations like group by, order by typically requires over 2x time. As a result, it would usually be beneficial to do the group by before union (of course this depends on actual data).

Comment: @Fat P I got your point about the group by / order by before the union. I am just confused about why it is necessary for TabC at all? Since the ID is primary key, the ID, Value pair will be unique in TabC and hence group by will always get 1 row for each ID. I am not sure if I am asking the correct question here but please try to help and let me know if I said anything incorrect.

Comment: Please don't misuse Stackoverflow and escpecially the comment function for discussions about how SQL works. If you have a look to the guidelines, you will see this is not intended. Please create a new, specific question if you need further assistance.

Answer (score 1):

Please define the expected result if an `ID` has same `LastUpdated` in `TabB` and `TabC` but different `Value`s. In following it is undefined.

```
WITH BC AS (
    SELECT ID, VALUE FROM (
        SELECT ID, VALUE, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY LastUpdated DESC) r
        FROM (
            SELECT ID, Value, MAX(LastUpdated) AS LastUpdated
            FROM TabB
            GROUP BY ID, Value
            UNION ALL
            SELECT ID, Value, MAX(LastUpdated) AS LastUpdated
            FROM TabC
            GROUP BY ID, Value
        )
    )
    WHERE R = 1
)
SELECT ID, VALUE FROM BC
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, 'N' VALUE FROM tabA A
WHERE A.ID NOT IN (
    SELECT ID FROM BC
)
ORDER BY ID;
```

Comment: Thanks @Jonas Metzler. Sorry for mistakenly clicked submit when I was still testing. Should be OK now.

Comment: Added as advised

Answer (score 0):

Use `UNION` to create a single data set from multiple tables.  Then, filter on that data set.

```
SELECT ID, Value
FROM
(
    SELECT ID, Value, MAX(LastUpdated) AS LastUpdated
    FROM TabB
    GROUP BY ID, Value
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ID, Value, MAX(LastUpdated) AS LastUpdated
    FROM TabC
    GROUP BY ID, Value
) t
WHERE ID IN
(
    SELECT DISTINCT ID
    FROM TabA
)
AND
(
    Value = 'Y' OR
    NOT EXISTS
    (
        SELECT 1
        FROM
        (
            SELECT ID, Value
            FROM
            (
                SELECT ID, Value, MAX(LastUpdated) AS LastUpdated
                FROM TabB
                GROUP BY ID, Value
                UNION ALL
                SELECT ID, Value, MAX(LastUpdated) AS LastUpdated
                FROM TabC
                GROUP BY ID, Value
            ) t
            WHERE ID = t.ID
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: will this query return data if Value is 'N'? Also there may be more IDs in TabB and TabC, so putting the first condition in where clause will restrict it from picking up all the IDs IMO. Please correct me if I am wrong